# i am using selenium and chrome closes instantly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
site=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Mehmet\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
site.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

When i run it youtube opens but after it closes instantly

Comment: If that's the entirety of your code, then it's doing exactly what you've told it to do. It's unclear what the problem is and what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
site=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Mehmet\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
site.get('https://www.youtube.com')

input("Press ENTER to exit")
```

Your code simply runs to the end, and the Chrome closing is expected